# Scaled Images Don't accessible in Grid view with right way

Tags: swift, image-processing, swiftui, swiftui-list, image-scaling

[Main View Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSrjq.png) , [My Subview Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGfby.png)My CardView is in ZStack  and, when stretching the background image, didn't select in the right way a GridView in Main View here is my codes of main and subview

```
                ScrollView {

                    NavigationLink("", destination: CardCategoryView(cardCategoryVm: .init(card: cardsVm.selectedCard)), isActive: $cardsVm.isShowingCardCategory)
                        LazyVGrid(columns: gridColoumns,spacing: 8) {
                            
                            ForEach(cardsVm.cards?.vendor ?? [] ,id: \.self) { symbol in
                                
                                
                             
                             
                               
                                    
                                    StoreCardView(image: symbol.image ?? "")
                              
                                        .frame(width:  UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 20,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 20)
                                        .padding(.top)
                  
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        let _ = print(symbol.name)
                                    cardsVm.selectedCard = symbol
                                    cardsVm.isShowingCardCategory = true
                                }


                                    
   

                            }
                            
                        }
            
                }
```

```
struct StoreCardView: View {
    var image:String
   
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            
                ZStack{
                 
                    KFImage(URL(string:image))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaleEffect(x: 3, y: 3, anchor: .center)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: reader.size.width , height: reader.size.height  , alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .blur(radius: 25, opaque: true)
                        .opacity(0.7)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                      
                    
                    KFImage(URL(string:image))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio( contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: reader.size.width/2, height: reader.size.height/2, alignment: .center)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(color: .movColor.opacity(0.4),radius: 5,
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0
                        )

                        
//
                } .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
             
          
        }
    }
}
```

I made it in Ztack and gave it a fixed frame with Scale Effect and it didn't work also, how can I make the background image stretching and didn't effect on gridview at main view